# How to get results not between two dates?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, between

I have two dates that property has been blocked on that two days like start date 2017-01-20 and end end 2017-01-25. Between these two dates property has been blocked. When I search with these two dates except these two dates I want to get the remaining dates.

Here I have tried by searching the web in MySQL like

```
select `pd`.*, `pa`.*
from `property_details` as `pd` left join
     `property_gallery` as `pg`
     on `pg`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id` left join
     `property_preblock_details` as `pbd`
     on `pbd`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id` left join
     `property_amenity` as `pa`
     on `pa`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id`
 where `pbd`.`start_date` >= '2017-01-20'  and `pbd`.`end_date` <= '2017-01-25'
```

and

```
select pd.* from 
    `property_details` as `pd` left join 
    `property_gallery` as `pg` on `pg`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id` 
    left join `property_preblock_details` as `pbd` 
    on `pbd`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id` 
    left join `property_amenity` as `pa`
    on `pa`.`property_id` = `pd`.`property_id` 
 where `pbd`.`start_date` NOT BETWEEN CAST('2017-01-20' AS DATE) and CAST('2017-01-25' AS DATE) 
 AND `pbd`.`end_date` NOT BETWEEN CAST('2017-01-20' AS DATE) and CAST('2017-01-25' AS DATE)
```

But I'm getting results as between dates.

I don't want to get between dates results, I want to get not between dates results.

**Property_rate**

```
id    start_date    end_date     prop_id
1     2017-01-20    2017-01-25     1
2     2017-01-26    2017-01-27     1
3     2017-01-26    2017-01-28     2
```

**Property**

```
prop_id  prop_name
1        test1
2        test2
```

If I select 2017-01-20 and 2017-01-25, I want to get 'test2' property details only. Not 'test1' details.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: is your date data type  varchar?

Comment: no its datetime

Comment: You have rows in your `property_rate` table for both `prop_id` 1 and 2 that pass the date filter you've described. It looks to me like you wish to entirely exclude any `prop_id` from your result set if it has *any* row in `property_rate` matching your date range. I suspect your best course of action is to refine your statement of requirements, then try to refine your query logic. You might do well to come back and ask another question when you have done that.

Answer (score 0):

You've very close.  Your query says this:

```
    where `pbd`.`start_date` >= '2017-01-20'   /* close, but wrong */
      and `pbd`.`end_date` <= '2017-01-25'
```

What you want is this:

```
    where (    `pbd`.`start_date` < '2017-01-20'  
           or  `pbd`.`end_date`  > '2017-01-25')
```

It can also be written

```
    where not (      `pbd`.`start_date` >= '2017-01-20' 
                 and `pbd`.`end_date` <= '2017-01-25')
```

**BEWARE** Your query may have another mistake in it. If your `start_date` and `end_date` columns have the `DATE` data type, you're all set.  But if they have another data type, such as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, your query has another problem. To catch all the rows with date/time values on the days 20-Jan-2017 -- 25-Jan-2017 you need this

```
where `pbd`.`start_date` >= '2017-01-20'   /*dates IN range */
  and `pbd`.`end_date` < '2017-01-26'
```

Notice I moved the desired end date one day later and used `<` instead of `<=`. This works correctly for

```
          2017-01-25 23:59     should be in range
          2017-01-26 00:00     should be out of range
          2017-01-26 00:01     should be out of range
```

Comment: With is also i'm getting in between results :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE  `DATECOLUMN` NOT 
IN (

SELECT  'ID'
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE  `DATECOLUMN` 
BETWEEN (
'2017-02-10 00:00:00'
)
AND (
'2017-09-14 00:00:00'
)
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```